# Parent object variable throwing error when assessed in function Python

Tags: python, class, pygame

So I'm working on a Pygame game, and I am working on the player. The player is a child class of BaseClass, which has the x/y of the object, sprite, and the frameEvent function stub. I am making the player's frameEvent, (Executed once per frame) and it looks like this:

```
def frameEvent(self):

    # Get the currently pressed keys
    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # Check if we should move the player
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x += 5
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 5
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        y += 5
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 5
```

However; when I run it, I get this when I press a key:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Fun Stuff\Python Stuff\Python projects\SimpleEngine\Main.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Fun Stuff\Python Stuff\Python projects\SimpleEngine\Main.py", line 57, in main
    ObjPlayer.frameEvent()
  File "E:\Fun Stuff\Python Stuff\Python projects\SimpleEngine\oPlayer.py", line 31, in frameEvent
    x += 5
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this. I just started doing Python 2 weeks ago after doing the Codeacedemy Python thing, so I know mostly just basic syntax. (Although I do know Gamemaker's built in language: GML very well)

Any help with said issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is an instance variable, use `self.x` to refer to it. Same for `y`. Note that they must be initialized to something for the `+=` operator to work properly, since `+=` uses the current value of the left-hand side operand to compute the new value.